# Namecheap API: XML reader exception in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xmlreader, namecheap

I am having a problem while deserializing an XML:

```
[XmlRoot("ProductCategory")]
public class ProductCategory
{
    public Product[] Products;
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlArray("Product")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ProductPrice", typeof(ProductPrice))]
    public ProductPrice[] Prices;
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Duration;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DurationType;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal Price;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal RegularPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal YourPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string CouponPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Currency;
}
```

and this is the action:

```
public ProductType GetPricing()
        {
            XDocument doc = new Query(_params)
              .AddParameter("ProductType", "DOMAIN")
              .AddParameter("ActionName","REGISTER")
              .Execute("namecheap.users.getPricing");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductType), _ns.NamespaceName);

            using (var reader = doc.Root.Element(_ns + "CommandResponse").Element(_ns + "ProductType").CreateReader())
            {
                return (ProductType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
```

I am getting this error:
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i5c.png)

And here you can find example of the xml: https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/users/get-pricing.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you're missing XML namespace here, which is `http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found number of issues with your code. Here is the working code

First you will have to have the objects defined as below

```
[XmlRoot("ProductType", Namespace = "http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response")]
public class ProductType
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ProductCategory")]
    public ProductCategory[] ProductCategories;
}
public class ProductCategory
{
    [XmlElement("Product")]
    public Product[] Products;
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("Price")]
    public ProductPrice[] Prices;
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Duration;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DurationType;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal Price;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal RegularPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public decimal YourPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string CouponPrice;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Currency;
}
```

Here is the code to deserialize it

```
var serializerx = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductType), "http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response");
XElement doc = XElement.Load("sample1.xml");
XNamespace ns = doc.Name.Namespace;
var e = doc.Element(ns + "CommandResponse").Element(ns + "UserGetPricingResult").Element(ns + "ProductType");

using (var reader = e.CreateReader())
{
    var prod =  (ProductType)serializerx.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Hope this helps